# CSS fallbacks (display)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Does putting more modern CSS after fallback code work without any other additions?

For example:

```
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33rem);
    justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
```

Would use grid if supported, and flex if not, with the items spaced evenly with space between as the fallback? I just want to make sure that the repeated attributes are ignored rather than invalidated entirely.

Sorry if this seems easy, but I haven't been able to find an obvious way to test it myself in the browser!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, These ways to provide support when it comes to CSS.

**Method 1:** Write fallback code. Overwrite fallback code.

```
.selector {
  property: fallback-value;
  property: actual-value;
}
```

**Method 2:** Write fallback code. Overwrite fallback code in CSS Feature Queries `(@supports)`. Reset properties inside `@supports` if you need.

```
.selector {
  property: fallback-value;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  property: actual-value;
}
```

This means writing everything in `@supports` **is the simplest of the three.**

**Example:**

**SCSS :**

```
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  @supports (display: grid) {
    display: grid;  
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(290px, 1fr));
  }
}
```

Comment: I would argue the third method is pretty much the same as having no fallback at all, and therefor not worth doing unless you also have the fallback outside of the `@supports` (Like method 2)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I knew `@supports` was an option, but didn't want to go down the 'does it support `@supports`' rabbit hole :). Think I'll stick to the overwriting of display, and ignore old browsers outside of that for the time being